# Why my program does not print the code that comes after the switch case? It ends after switch case is executed and that is it

Tags: c, switch-statement

The code works fine if I hide the switch case. If I enter invalid int for the switch case, it will execute the printf statements after the switch case. If I enter valid int for the switch case it will enter the switch case and ends there, skipping the printf statements afterward. It looks fine but apparently it is not?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define OT 14.00

void main ()
{
    char name[40];
    char position[20];
    char position_name[20];
    int id, o_time, code;
    float allowance, bonus, nett_salary, salary;
    
    printf ("-----------------------------------");
    printf ("\n         PAYROLL SYSTEM");
    printf ("\n-----------------------------------");
    printf ("\n      1. Lecturer");
    printf ("\n      2. Clerk");
    printf ("\n      3. Technician");
    printf ("\n-----------------------------------");

    printf ("\nEnter staff name     : ");
    scanf("%[^\n]s",&name);
    printf ("Enter staff ID       : ");
    scanf ("%d", &id);
    printf ("Enter position       : ");
    scanf ("%d", &code);
    printf ("Enter salary         : RM ");
    scanf ("%f", &salary);
    
    
    
    
    switch (code)
    {
        case 1:
        strcpy (position, "Lecturer");
        printf ("Enter allowance      : RM ");
        scanf ("%f", allowance);
        nett_salary = salary+allowance;
        break;
        
        case 2:
        strcpy (position, "Clerk");
        printf ("Enter bonus          : RM ");
        scanf ("%f", bonus);
        nett_salary = salary+bonus;
        break;
        
        case 3:
        strcpy (position, "Technician");
        printf ("Enter overtime hours : ");
        scanf ("%d", o_time);
        nett_salary = salary+(o_time*OT);
        break;
        
        default:
        strcpy(position,"Invalid");
        nett_salary = 0;
    }
    
    printf ("\nStaff Name      : %s", name);
    printf ("\nStaff No.       : %d", id);
    printf ("\nPosition        : %s", position);    
    printf ("\nSalary          : RM%.2f", salary);
    printf ("\n------------------------------------");
    printf ("\nNett Salary     : RM %.2f", nett_salary);
    printf ("\n------------------------------------");
    
    
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%[^\n]s",&name);` is bad...you should use `fgets()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scanf ("%f", allowance); // In case 1
scanf ("%f", bonus);     // In case 2
scanf ("%d", o_time);    // In case 3
```

`&` is missing in these `scanf` statments.

Answer (score 0):

The primary problems are in

```
 scanf ("%f", allowance);
```

where you're missing the `&` operator to the supplied argument, same for all case statements.

That said, do not use `scanf()` for user-inputs, it has many drawbacks. Use `fgets()` instead.

Comment: thanks! this one works! and noted, i'll use fgets

Answer (score 0):

You use this caracter  **&** to put the variable in it's adress

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define OT 14.00

void main ()
{
char name[40];
char position[20];
char position_name[20];
int id=0, o_time=0, code=0;
float allowance, bonus, nett_salary, salary;

printf ("-----------------------------------");
printf ("\n         PAYROLL SYSTEM");
printf ("\n-----------------------------------");
printf ("\n      1. Lecturer");
printf ("\n      2. Clerk");
printf ("\n      3. Technician");
printf ("\n-----------------------------------");

printf ("\nEnter staff name     : ");
fgets(name,40,stdin);//use fgets insted of scanf
printf ("Enter staff ID       : ");
scanf ("%d", &id);
printf ("Enter position       : ");
scanf ("%d", &code);
printf ("Enter salary         : RM ");
scanf ("%f", &salary);



switch (code)
{
    case 1:
    strcpy (position, "Lecturer");
    printf ("Enter allowance      : RM ");
    scanf ("%f",&allowance);//you forget &
    nett_salary = (float)salary+allowance;
    break;

    case 2:
    strcpy (position, "Clerk");
    printf ("Enter bonus          : RM ");
    scanf ("%f", &bonus);//you forget &
    nett_salary = salary+bonus;
    break;

    case 3:
    strcpy (position, "Technician");
    printf ("Enter overtime hours : ");
    scanf ("%d", &o_time);//you forget &
    nett_salary = salary+(o_time*OT);
    break;

    default:
    strcpy(position,"Invalid");
    nett_salary = 0;
    break;
}
printf ("\nStaff Name      : %s", name);
printf ("\nStaff No.       : %d", id);
printf ("\nPosition        : %s", position);
printf ("\nSalary          : RM%.2f", salary);
printf ("\n------------------------------------");
printf ("\nNett Salary     : RM %.2f", nett_salary);
printf ("\n------------------------------------");
}
```